# Changing the icon of the produced .exe, py2exe

Tags: python, compiler-construction, py2exe

Ive been googling this however none of the results worked for me.

Here is my setup file

```
setup(
windows = [
    {
        "script": "start.py",
        "icon_resources": [(1, "myicon.ico")]
    }
],
)
```

The icon of the actual .exe file should be "myicon.ico". However this does not happen and is the default icon. "myicon.ico" is 32 x 32.

I am using windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding icon in .exe with py2exe, visible in Vista?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525329/embedding-icon-in-exe-with-py2exe-visible-in-vista)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had this problem before (though I'm using windows XP).  A recent snippet of code that worked for me:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    zipfile = None,
    windows = [{
            "script":"myprogram.pyw",
            "icon_resources": [(1, "myicon.ico")],
            "dest_base":"myprogram"
            }],
)
```

This creates one .exe file that you can use to distribute  (even includes windows libs -- so use caution there)

My .ico file was 64 x 64 and I used a tool to create it from a JPG (something like http://www.favicon.cc/)  Sometimes with Photoshop and GIMP saving a file as .ico with default settings is not quite enough, so be aware you might have to do something else there.