# How to add an icon to an exe developed through py2exe

Tags: python, icons, installation, py2exe

I am working on windows-7 64 bit machine using python 2.7.
Using **py2exe** to convert mycode.py script into an exe. I am not able to find the reason why icon to an exe is not embedded.

My setup.py is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import time
setup(
    windows=[{'script':'MyScript.pyw',
    'icon_resources':[(1,'MyIcon.ico')}],
    options=dict(py2exe=dict(
        packages='keyring.backends',
    )),
)
time.sleep(2)
```

I also looked into [CustomIcons](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons), [q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525329/embedding-icon-in-exe-with-py2exe-visible-in-vista).

Answer (score 2):

[Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) might be helpful.

Comment: yes, It worked, but can it be possible through py2exe. py2exe has option to add icon